# Infer arguments based on return type

Tags: typescript

Given the following code, I would like to infer the `message` parameter based on the return type of `_stepResult`.

For some reason I can get it to work when changing the `_stepResult` return type to `_stepResult: () => T`.

```
type Txt = { type: "message"; text: string; };
type Image = { type: "image"; url: string; };
type TextMessage = { type: 'message'; text: string; };
type ImageMessage = { type: 'image', description: string; url: string; };

type StepMap = {
  message: [Txt, TextMessage];
  image: [Image, ImageMessage];
};

const handleFn = <T extends keyof StepMap>(
  name: string,
  _stepResult: () => StepMap[T][1],
  _stepResultFn: (message: StepMap[T][0]) => StepMap[T][0]
) => {};

const messageStep = handleFn(
  'start',
  () => {
    return {
      type: 'message',
      text: '123'
    };
  },
  ({ type, text }) => {
    return { text, type  };
  }
);

const imageStep = handleFn(
  'image_step',
  () => {
    return {
      type: 'image',
      description: 'img description',
      url: 'test.nl'
    }
  },
  ({ type, url }) => {
    return { url, type };
  }
);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgHsKBeKBvAsAKClUkBcUARALYQDO5AhgOYREDcWOwECh5wATgJYB2NJpgC%20QrHmgBJErWgoM2XOAiEiPGXUbMoAVy4AbDt36CsorOOWw2wALIVqdZGm0TCAcjKVZ7oSxtGvAJC5piWkFDSsvbeTvKuyh7qPgA02gAmFADGvGDAPAD2fIEmfroGJQJpImKYElAxjhTOMDaNslAAPpEaEO10FnVWAMqsYLZUYM4KOF5NhADa8MAp1gj9EAC6Zcl0i1F0qwd9DrLbZrVZRZxQABZUfOn6EABifM4APDBQNhCP5FAANYQEAFABmUFGEHGk1WACUfgg-ukAVCYWAlpsFgBGTYAPgAFNo%20FQyJUaNUcAB9TjQuEUHT6YCEAkASmQeKgcMpUBpY3p5EZwDeLLmskIaImGJgWIADJt2UhOZLJpiFvKsIrOTMoFwIMA9O9UKFQlgrnwbmK6GjnPdHs83kTFO5OFQuMB3Dy2RyXIocHqDVwjdocCxElBPKc6J6Q6HWOwI9iAEwAZncsdCOGEXtQSkgq3jiGEWt9od1%20sNpbLuBsPLLEjrUEzTc1l2uiF2EBtKDtT1efCdOHcnb50Jjim9Sqr-orQencfDw964%20rUEy5ByPDyhWKEfUNDX2Vy%20SKK%20rekMEdYnAAdHx9Om-S3FNntATcw3yvomyWdTPA8GT44BejZhvmGZlMIrZYEAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't currently infer a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `T` from [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) like `StepMap[T][1]`.  There have been various suggestions for it to do so, such as [microsoft/TypeScript#51612](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51612), but for now it's not part of the language.

Generally speaking if you want to infer a generic type parameter from the type of an argument you should simplify the relationship between those two types as much as possible.  You can't infer `T` from `() => StepMap[T][1]`, but you *can* infer `T` from `() => T`.  So the approach that works (and presumably this is what you're mentioning) is to make `T` correspond to the return type of `_stepResult`, and then use that `T` to compute the corresponding param/return type of `_stepResultFn`.  Possibly like this:

```
type StepPair = [Txt, TextMessage] | [Image, ImageMessage]
type StepMapZero<T> = Extract<StepPair, [any, T]>[0]

const handleFn = <T extends StepPair[1]>(
  name: string,
  _stepResult: () => T,
  _stepResultFn: (message: StepMapZero<T>) => StepMapZero<T>
) => {
  return {};
};
```

Here I've refactored your `StepMap` to just a `StepPair` [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and then implemented `StepMapZero<T>` to [`Extract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) the relevant member of `StepPair` corresponding to `T` and index into its `0` element.

We can see that it works as desired:

```
const messageStep = handleFn(
  'start',
  () => { return { type: 'message', text: '123' }; },
  ({ type, text }) => { return { text, type, }; }
); // okay

const imageStep = handleFn(
  'image_step',
  () => { return { type: 'image', description: 'desc', url: 'test.nl' } },
  ({ type, url }) => { return { url, type, }; }
); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-0E8I1bUTSDknRLShrZCYXx7Th3JWIDz1m7tB65dmdbnk24gy23VBMuQcjw8oVikHR1lh3pDEHWJwAHR8fRx4SJzv95T9BeZz3JnN+r0LtN7+MMeOlrBAA)

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks you for the simple explanation, Makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: One more question, if I change the `url` property of `Image` to `text` it stops working again? I thought it inferred the type based on the `type` property but I guess that's not how it works?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean; are you saying you are passing an invalid `Image`?  Without a [mre] I can't be sure what to say about it, but it does not specifically care about the `type` property (given that `StepPair` and `StepMapZero<T>` don't mention `type` in their definitions it would be weird if it did).